# ZXing performing badly in iOS?

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner

I have put some days to implement a barcode scanner which uses the framework ZXing. Now when It works I realise that it doesn't perform well at all, it is slow, inaccurate etc. Even ZXing's own application in App Store performs badly.

So my question is, is there some way to configure the accuracy etc. for an improved performance? I've been told that ZBar has several options for this.

Right now I am considering to use ZBar instead, I am just throwing this out there in case someone has an answer.

Comment: If you app is iOS 7 + only, you can also try using Apple's own barcode/QR code APIS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureMetadataOutput/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however the app needs to work on older iOS-versions.

Comment: I changed the resolution of the video: self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh; which made the performance much better, but it is still too slow in a room with less light.